# How to load the content of a show method in laravel on the index method using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have two methods show and index I have a list of items on the index method that when a user clicks it takes her to another page containing some data that belongs to that id. Instead of doing it such way, I want to use jquery  to make the data load on the same page. I have the following on my `index.blade.php` view. How do I achieve this in laravel?

```
  @foreach ($categories as $category)

    <div class="body">
    <h4><a style="text-decoration: none; " href="{{ URL::route('category.show', $category->id) }}">{{$category->name}}</a></h4>

    </div>
   @endforeach

<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use illuminate\HttpResponse;
 use App\Http\Requests\todolistRequest;
 use App\Http\Requests\CreateCategoryRequest;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Companylist;
 use App\Category;
 use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 class CategoryController extends Controller
 {

public function create(){
return view('category.create');
 }

 public function index(){
 $categories=Category::all();
 return view('category.index',compact('categories'));
 }
  public function store(CreateCategoryRequest $request){
 $category = new Category($request->all());
 $category->save();

  return \Redirect::route('category.create')->with('message',      'Your list has been created!'); 
  }
  public function show($id)
  {
  $category = Category::findOrFail($id)->companylist()->get();
  $cat=Category::findOrFail($id);
// this my route
   Route::resource('category','CategoryController');

      return                           view('category.show')->with('category',                          $category)->with('cat',$cat);
 }
```

//
     }

Comment: The "shift" key is that long button bottom left on your keyboard. [Use this regularly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), it significantly improves your chance to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bootstrap modals or pop ups.
Design your `category.show` view according to your needs.
Call ajax and append your returned view response to that modal body and show it so it will be exactly same view you wanted.

example code is for replace and ajax is like

This is replace modal

```
<!-- Show Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Show data</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body replace">

  </div>
</div>
```

This will be your ajax method

```
      $('.showModalButton').on('click',function(e){
        var id = $(this).data('id'); // get id of resource you want to show
        $('.replace').empty(); // 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your route/'+id,
            type: "GET",

            success:function(data) {
                $('.replace').html(data);
                },
            error:function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jQXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                }
        }); //end Ajax call

    });
```

This will be your show method in controller

```
public function show($id)
   {
     $category = Category::findOrFail($id)->companylist()->get();
     $cat=Category::findOrFail($id);
     // this my route
     Route::resource('category','CategoryController');

      return view('category.show')->with('category',$category)->with('cat',$cat);
    }
```

Design category.show however you want to show your data.

Comment: any links on how to do that

Comment: does it helped @ShowoleOladayo ?

Comment: still trying to sort it out, the guy is talking about deleting and editing, what am trying to is just to load the content of such the show view on the index view

Comment: check my answer @ShowoleOladayo mark it solved if it helps.

Comment: i have tried my best to make you understand... @ShowoleOladayo